# Persistent variable for all list members inside a loop called every frame

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to add a sort of manager to handle all objects in a list and increase a float value that each individual member of the list has given a condition every single frame. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around the actual code I need though.

So say I've got an OverlapCircleAll or trigger checking for tagged objects in a certain radius. These objects are then added to a List (`foo`).

Then, I go through `foo` with a for loop and declare a float value `x` for each object.

What I need is for each object's `x` to increase when the object is also on another list, `bar`.

So something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
     float x;
     //or float x = 0;?

     if (bar.Contains(foo[i]))
     {
          x += 1f;
     }
}
```

The problem is, I can't figure out how to make the value of `x` persist each loop. This function is called in Update() so the idea is that the longer an object is in both `foo` and `bar`, the higher its value of `x` is. I don't know how to save the value of `x` for the next loop though. Ideally something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < foo.Count; i++)
{
     float x;

     if (lastX != null)
     {
          x = lastX;
     }
     else
     {
          x = 0;
     }

     if (bar.Contains(foo[i]))
     {
          x += 1f;
     }

     float lastX = x;
}
```

But I don't know a) how to save `lastX` for each object in the list and b) set `x` to `lastX` (because for each loop it creates a `lastX`).

I thought about storing each `x` in an array of floats and calling the corresponding `array[i]` to `foo[i]` to get `x`, but if I remove something from the list then the array will become desynchronised with the list and all the `x` values will get muddled up.

What is the correct way to go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *correct way* is very different at times.

### Change variable scope

In the first part of the code you use `float x;` inside the for loop. This means `x` is in the *scope* of the for loop block, it is recreated every loop.

You can change the scope by declaring x outside of the loop, then it is recreated each (assumed) `Update` call. Since you would want x to persist between calls to `Update` you need to move it outside of it (change scope). This makes `x` a class variable (there are different names for that too) and looks like this:

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float x = 0f;

    void Update()
    {
        for(...) {...}
    }
}
```

### Keeping values where they belong to

Your second problem is a different story. For each element in your list you need a value x bounded to that element. This strongly suggests that x is part of that element. A good way to solve this is to add the `float x` to whatever type your elements are. If the elements are objects of one of your own classes, you can just add a new variable x to this class. Then access it using

```
foo[i].x
```

If the elements are objects of built in unity classes you can create a *Wrapper class* along the lines of:

```
public class MyElements
{
    public float x;
    public GameObject originalElement; // assumption...
}
```

Then when filling your list/array you fill it with `MyElements`.

All in all this is a basic C#/programming problem which is not related to game development. You can learn how to do this in various tutorials/books or other resources. If you need assistance, update your question or post a new one (preferrably on a suitable stackexchange site).

#### Final note

As you realized, it is difficult to properly handle a parallel list of `x`. No question it can be done but it is very error prone.

Comment: Thanks a ton, this helped a lot. I made a wrapper class and everything's working exactly how I want it to. Thanks for the in-depth response! I realise now I probably should have put this on StackOverflow or something, my bad ahaha